# Ajax POST method erroring and not sure why

Tags: javascript, ajax

When running post request, we are getting this error and not sure why. The post is running to the database however we can't get the success call back function running as we get this error:

> Error, status = parsererror, error thrown: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

Code:

```
$(document).on('click', '#bookbutton', function(){

            $.ajax({

              type:    "POST",

         url:     "...." + searchfrom + "&todate=" + searchto + "&VanID=" + String(this.name),

              success: function(data) {

                    alert("van booked succesfully");

              },

              error:   function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                    console.log("Error, status = " + textStatus + ", " +

                          "error thrown: " + errorThrown

                    );

              }

            });

          });

        });
```

I tried a lot of things but no success.

Comment: Use your browser's network tab to retrieve the JSON response, and paste it here in a code block inside your question body, so readers can see it. It sounds to me like the response is not JSON at all.

Comment: Also, have a look at the HTTP response code and tell us what it is, again by editing your post.